# Read data from Visual Fox Pro database with C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-foxpro

I am able to make a Data Connection to a Visual Fox Pro database, from it I need to 2 tables. How do I join the 2 tables then retrieve the data in C#?

Comment: Have you tried a SQL join statement? Foxpro supports SQL-92 joins.

Answer (score 6):

First, I would [download Microsoft's Visual FoxPro OleDb provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839).

Once downloaded and installed, you can use it for connecting to the PATH where the database tables are located.  Additionally, if the app is using a "database" where the tables are properly linked, you can explicitly include the database name too.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public class YourClass
{
   public DataTable GetYourData()
   {
      DataTable YourResultSet = new DataTable();

      OleDbConnection yourConnectionHandler = new OleDbConnection(
          "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\\SomePath\\;" );

      // if including the full dbc (database container) reference, just tack that on
//      OleDbConnection yourConnectionHandler = new OleDbConnection(
//          "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\\SomePath\\NameOfYour.dbc;" );


      // Open the connection, and if open successfully, you can try to query it
      yourConnectionHandler.Open();

      if( yourConnectionHandler.State == ConnectionState.Open )
      {
         OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
         string mySQL = "select A1.*, B1.* "
                     + " from FirstTable A1 "
                     + "      join SecondTable B1 "
                     + "         on A1.SomeKey = B1.SomeKey "
                     + " where A1.WhateverCondition ";  // blah blah...

         OleDbCommand MyQuery = new OleDbCommand( mySQL, yourConnectionHandle );

         DA.SelectCommand = MyQuery;

         DA.Fill( YourResultSet );

         yourConnectionHandle.Close();
      }

      return YourResultSet;
   }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the OP already knows how to create connections.  What he wants to do is join two tables together to create a view.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yup... just showing the full steps through, in case problem with connection... Also, some people try to connect to the actual "TABLE" as opposed to just creating a connection... Does it actually connect? or not... That's why the extended answer.

Comment: I got an error when copying this, after I added DA.SelectCommand = MyQuery then it worked

Comment: @reggaeguitar, thanks for feedback and nobody noticed otherwise and it was a sample from memory and obviously not perfect, but glad you figured out the missing piece to get you rolling.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for a somewhat complete test.  You will need to download the VFPOLEDB driver from Microsoft.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
        "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=F:\\Gutters\\Data\\database.dbc;"
    );
                connection.Open();
                DataTable tables = connection.GetSchema(
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables
                );

                foreach (System.Data.DataRow rowTables in tables.Rows)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(rowTables["table_name"].ToString());
                    DataTable columns = connection.GetSchema(
                        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns,
                        new String[] { null, null, rowTables["table_name"].ToString(), null }
                    );
                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow rowColumns in columns.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine(
                            rowTables["table_name"].ToString() + "." +
                            rowColumns["column_name"].ToString() + " = " +
                            rowColumns["data_type"].ToString()
                        );
                    }
                }

                string sql = "select * from customer";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);

                DataTable YourResultSet = new DataTable();
                OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                DA.Fill(YourResultSet);
            }
        }
    }
```